# Unable to pass through a function in to class constructor

Tags: javascript

I have a function created to perform certain actions on our mysql database, but I am only get it to work by including the module in to each function within the class, whereas i would ideally like to place it in the constructor to reduce code repetition but it doesn't seem to initiate the sql function file.

This is the class initiator:

```
class fetchGameItems {

    // Create [Functions] Class
    constructor(id, sql_game, sql_player) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sql_game = require(`./mysql_game.js`);
        this.sql_player = require(`./mysql_player.js`);
    }

    // Obtain [Items] from [Game Database]
    async Items(id, sql_game, sql_player) {

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

And i have tried several methods to get the function processed on construction with no luck.

This is the latest iteration of my function call:

```
const id = args[0];
    const fetchGameItemsFile = require('../../../functions/combined function');
    const fetchGameItems = new fetchGameItemsFile(id, sql_game, sql_player;

    const gameItems = await fetchGameItems.Items(id, sql_game, sql_player);
```

How would i get a file require to work inside a class constructor and to run the script?

Comment: what are you requiring? an entire `.js` file? are you not working with `modules` and `exports`?

Comment: There's a part in your code that's halfway done - the line with the `new Promise()` is just halfway code.